# How to add a button to MUI TextField Select component selected option?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI v5 `Textfield select` component. Each option has a `play button`, `avatar` and `option text`. Everything works fine in dropdown list. But how can I make `play button` work (do something) if it is selected? At the moment if user clicks on it then option list opens.

```
const StyledSelect = ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <TextField {...props} select fullWidth>
      {props.children}
    </TextField>
  );
};

export const AudioSelect = () => {
  return (
    <StyledSelect>
      {AUDIO_OPTIONS.map(({ id, name, avatar, voice }) => (
        <MenuItem key={id} value={id}>
          <Stack>
            <PlayAudioButton
              sound={voice}
              key={id}
              onPlay={() => console.log("play button " + id)}
              isPlaying={false}
            />
            <Avatar src={avatar} />
            <Typography>{name}</Typography>
          </Stack>
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </StyledSelect>
  );
};
```

Here's codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-monad-6z3144?file=/src/AudioSelect.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another propagation stopping in `onMouseDown` did the trick

```
  return (
    <IconButton
      onMouseDown={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }}
      onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        onPlay();
      }}
    >
      {isPlaying && !isAudioEnded ? <PauseIcon /> : <PlayArrowRoundedIcon />}
    </IconButton>
  );
```

[image: Edit wonderful-silence-6movrx]